# Using timeout NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm trying to make an automatic check up after X minutes when an API route is called.
I was planning on using CRON task, but found that timeout function will be easier and faster to implement and was working.

My only concern regards performances, my timeout function just make a Mongoose request and send an email depend on an "if condition". Is using timeout function using a lot of my dedicated servers performances ? Or can I just go with it ?

Thanks !

Comment: If your process dies, then your scheduled timeouts will also die with that.

Comment: Use a consumer/producer pattern with aws SQS. That will be reliable.